# FileSystemWatcher not found in Xamarin

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

Hi  I am working with Xamarin and am looking at building a FileSystemWatcher. I have seen that there are some out there already, but I need to perform specific actions when a specific file is changed.

Using Xamarin on the Mac I am using C# and am trying to use `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`, however I am getting an error saying

> the type or namespace 'FileSystemWatcher' could not be found.

However, in this link [Xamarin site](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher/) it states that is should be in here as a base class.

In addition to this I have already got at the top a using statement to bring System.IO in to scope, and using just FileSystemWatcher too but this has not helped either.

Would appreciate help fro experience Xamarin users to tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mac/FSEvents/